# NetworkX / Pandas - how output the communities group of each node into a .txt

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I need to ouput the community of each node of a network into a .txt file. 
I'm using NetworkX ver. 2.1 and Pandas ver. 0.23.4:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
from networkx.algorithms import community

G = nx.barbell_graph(5, 1)
communities_generator = community.girvan_newman(G)
top_level_communities = next(communities_generator)
next_level_communities = next(communities_generator)
sorted(map(sorted, next_level_communities))

#>>> sorted(map(sorted, next_level_communities))
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
#in this case, 3 different communities (groups) were identified
```

I need a .txt table similar to:

```
NODE    COMMUNITY
0   GROUP 1
1   GROUP 1
2   GROUP 1
3   GROUP 1
4   GROUP 1
5   GROUP 2
6   GROUP 3
7   GROUP 3
8   GROUP 3
9   GROUP 3
10  GROUP 3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
from networkx.algorithms import community

G = nx.barbell_graph(5, 1)
communities_generator = community.girvan_newman(G)
top_level_communities = next(communities_generator)
next_level_communities = next(communities_generator)

data = [[element, "GROUP-{}".format(ii + 1)] for ii, st in enumerate(next_level_communities) for element in sorted(st)]
print(data)

frame = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['node', 'community'])
frame.to_csv("communities.csv", sep=" ", index=False)
```

The file 'communities.csv' has the following format:

```
node community
0 GROUP-1
1 GROUP-1
2 GROUP-1
3 GROUP-1
4 GROUP-1
5 GROUP-2
6 GROUP-3
7 GROUP-3
8 GROUP-3
9 GROUP-3
10 GROUP-3
```